# Clojure equivalent of Erlang's DETS / Persistent-Maps

Tags: clojure, dets

I'm looking for the equivalent of Erlangs DETS for a persistent key/value store,
 except with out DETS 2G table size limit.

Comment: mnesia could be if no clojure option exists. Pulling in erlang and mnesia to the build is OK just more work.

Comment: there have been a lot of good dets competitors for clojure produced since this question was asked.

Answer (score 3):

[Berkeley DB Java Edition](http://www.oracle.com/database/berkeley-db/je/index.html) (with Clojure-wrapper available [here](http://github.com/gcv/cupboard)) is pretty nice. The basic stuff is relatively straightforward, and should the need arise it supports replication and other high availability features. It seems that the license is more GPL-like than LGPL-like, so I think for closed-source applications (even without modifications to BDB JE itself), you'd need a separate license.

Comment: I need to store thousands of 10 meg binaries. total size about 100G will it fall over